Adding angles to triangle and labelling them inside?
I'm trying to draw an equilateral triangle in tikz and want to include the angles inside and label them within the angle showing they are 60 degrees each but am now sure how to do this... here is my code:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (60:3) -- (3,0) -- cycle;
    \draw (1.5,-0.25) -- (1.5,0.25);
    \draw (0.5,1.5) -- (1.05,1.15);
    \draw (1.05,1.15) -- (0.5,1.5);
    \draw (2.05,1.15) -- (2.6,1.5);
    \node at (1.5,-1) {\textbf{Equilateral}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

I have tried to just draw parabolas or curves but I know there must be a faster way! Also not sure if there is an easier way to draw the equilateral line symbols I've included?
Any help would be great!

Welcome! Use the angles and quotes libraries.

Take a look at the package tkz-euclide and tkz-elements

With tkz-euclide.  Section 29.9. Mark a segment \tkzMarkSegment.
I declare the points with \tkzDefPoints and I create the equiallateral triangle with \tkzDefTriangle[equilateral](O,A).
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    % \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    % \coordinate (A) at (3,0);
    % \coordinate (B) at (60:3);
    % \draw (O)--(A)--(B)--cycle;
    %
    %    first solution
    %
    % \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O,3/0/A}
    % \tkzDefPoint(60:3){B}
    % 
    %   Or
    %
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O,3/0/A}
    \tkzDefTriangle[equilateral](O,A)
    \tkzGetPoint{B}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \tkzDrawPolygon(O,A,B)

    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.9, mark=none](A,O,B)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.6, font=\footnotesize](A,O,B){$60$°}

    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.9, mark=none](B,A,O)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.6, font=\footnotesize](B,A,O){$60$°}

    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.9, mark=none](O,B,A)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.6, font=\footnotesize](O,B,A){$60$°}

    \tkzMarkSegments[mark=||,size=6pt](O,A B,A B,O)%<-- added

    \node at (1.5,-1) {\textbf{Equilateral}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Use the angles and quotes libraries.
\documentclass[11pt,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) coordinate (A) -- (60:3) coordinate (B) -- (3,0) coordinate (C) -- cycle;
  \draw (1.5,-0.25) -- (1.5,0.25);
  \draw (0.5,1.5) -- (1.05,1.15);
  \draw (1.05,1.15) -- (0.5,1.5);
  \draw (2.05,1.15) -- (2.6,1.5);
  \node at (1.5,-1) {\textbf{Equilateral}};
  \draw pic [draw,"$\alpha$"] {angle=A--B--C};
  \draw pic [draw,"$\alpha$"] {angle=C--A--B};
  \draw pic [draw,"$\alpha$"] {angle=B--C--A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Note that you're not using the library you were loading, even though shapes.geometric could be used to draw the triangle.


UPDATE
I have modified my code to look like the following:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A) at (3,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (60:3);

    \draw (O)--(A)--(B)--cycle;

    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.9, mark=none](A,O,B)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.6, font=\footnotesize](A,O,B){$60\degree$}

    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.9, mark=none](B,A,O)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.6, font=\footnotesize](B,A,O){$60\degree$}

    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.9, mark=none](O,B,A)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.6, font=\footnotesize](O,B,A){$60\degree$}

    \node at (1.5,-1) {\textbf{Equilateral}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

which has yielded me the image below. My issue now is can I add the little lines on each side that show it's equilateral?


Please don't post followup questions into the answer space. If none of the answers you received help, you can self-answer if you found a solution. Alternatively, you can edit your original post to include additional information. Your original code had the sides of the triangle marked and my answer kept that feature. If you prefer another approach, that's fine. Again, either accept the relevant answer here and ask a followup or edit your original question.
